# Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents neither alpha transparency aren't working for wheel events?

Tags: c++, qt, events, qwidget, mousewheel

this line

```
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
```

is an old friend for everyone that works with Qt it propagates the event for the widget under the current one.

Also if you are using transparency in a button only the solid part of it gets this kind of events.

Unfortunatly I didn't manage to make the same for wheel events, obviously you can catch it throught eventFilter but this is not fine for me.

The idea is an overlay over a widget that contains 3d data so it "steals" the wheel event.